# Wordpress Customizer use back button to tearDown

Tags: javascript, wordpress

As in title, i would like to know if it's possible to creare a callback that is going to be fired once the user click on the `Go Back` button, in the top left of the Wordpress Customizer.

The main reason why, is because i would be able to clean up the DOM modification i perform into the customizer iframe for each section/panel when the user come back to the root in order to choose another section/panel and so on.